# I have around 1000 different activities in my Android App. How can I jump to a random activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

`Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,Q1.class);`

In my app I have 1000 different activities namely Q1,Q2,Q3....Q1000. 
I have a button on each activity and I want when a user clicks on it, he should land on some random activity. 
How to achieve this ?

Comment: Aside from being a terrible idea to create 1000 activities, what have you tried so far.

Comment: Having 1000 activities in itself a really bad idea. If the activities share a common "architecture" then why not have just one activity and update the values in the activity randomly on button click.

Comment: If I wish to display 1000 different questions to a user, one question at a time, what other methods would you suggest ?

Comment: at least not the equivalent of buying 1000 smartphones for the various apps I'd like to use ;) - seriously, how about putting your questions in a database and then having one activity with a TextView displaying one question at a time?

Comment: one Activity which display question details and initialize it with different question each time. pass a question in your Intent and get a different data for each question

Comment: @NarayanAcharya Thanks for the tip. I will try this.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Actually I just started coding and I don't know much about DataBase. All I have learned is Intent and Activities, So I came up with such a noob question.

Comment: 1000 Activities, 1000 Views, Waste over 2000 - 4000 Hours. Horrible.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein  Thanks for such a wonderful suggestion. That thought never crossed my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is terrible, I'll still show a possible way to do this. But just remember, **this is TERRIBLE**.

You can store all the activity classes in an `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Class<Activity>> activities = new ArrayList<> ();
```

And then you add all the activities into the `ArrayList`. Yeah, I know, this part is tedious. For example,

```
 activities.add (Activity1.class);
```

And then you create a `Random` called `rand` and use that to access an element in the list:

```
list.get (rand.nextInt (list.size()));
```

---

Here is another "better" way to do it, but it's still kinda bad. I strongly advise you to store teh questions in a database. Anyway, here's the better-but-still-bad method.

You create a question class:

```
public class Question  {
    //here you can put correctAnswer, questionText etc
}
```

After that, you make an `ArrayList` of `Question`s i.e. `ArrayList<Question>`.

```
ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<> ();
```

And still, you need to add 1000 questions to the array list. Then you can just use a `Random` to access it.

When you want to display a question in *one* activity, you can just `putExtra` in `Intent` before starting the activity. `putExtra` basically passes some "parameter" thingys to the activity. Then in the activity, you can just get the "Extra" and use the `Question` object to display. e.g. set the text of a `TextView` to the question text.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Sweeper. After getting ridiculed, I have decided to learn SQLite and then store all my questions in a DB. :)

Comment: You can use SugarORM! (http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) It's much simpler! @iAjaySinghBisht

Comment: Can't Thank You enough mate. Looking into it now. @Sweeper

Comment: @iAjaySinghBisht If you think my answer helps you, please accept it! Just click on the tick below the votes!

Answer (score 1):

this can be also used:

```
   try {
            Random rand=new Random();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Class.forName("test.hu.test.Q"+rand.nextInt(1000)+"")); // get activity's class by reflection
            startActivity(i);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

But i also suggest to use DB.